# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when submitting array from in ionic

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework

I have a voting result collector form I am developing in ionic

my database structure is this way

[image]

if you take a look at phoneNo **08033918581** on the table he was able to insert three result at once to the database. Doing this in php is no stress but I tried achieving the same aim in **ionic** using the same method I used in HTML but couldn't.

Below is my result.html in ionic

```
<ion-item class="mylist hideme">
<ion-input type="text"  *ngFor="let post of postList" value="{{post.phoneNo}}" placeholder="Phone" name="phones" #phones></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly  name="party[]" placeholder="APC"  value="apc"></ion-input>
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote[]" #vote></ion-input>

</ion-item>

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly name="party[]"  value="pdp"></ion-input>
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote[]" #vote></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly  name="party[]"  value="apga"></ion-input>  
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote[]" #vote></ion-input>
</ion-item>    

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly   name="party[]"  value="lp"></ion-input>
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote[]" #vote></ion-input>

</ion-item>

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly   name="party[]"  value="ivc"></ion-input> 
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Invalid vote cast" name="vote[]" #vote></ion-input>

</ion-item>

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly  readonly  name="party[]"  value="tvc"></ion-input>
<ion-input type="number"  placeholder="Total vote cast" name="vote[]" #vote></ion-input>

</ion-item>
<div class="padding">
<button ion-button  round   small (click)="submit()" class="btns ink fadeInUp">Add Result</button>
</div>
```

In my `.ts` I have this

```
@ViewChild("party")party;
@ViewChild("vote")vote; 
@ViewChild("phones")phones;
```

And for the send function

```
submit(){

  //// check to confirm the username, email, telephone and password fields are filled


  if(this.vote.value==""){

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

  title:"ATTENTION",

  subTitle:"Total vote cast is required. Enter 0 where not available.",

  buttons: ['OK']

  });

  alert.present();

  }

  else

  {

  var headers = new Headers();

  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let data = {

    party: this.party.value,
    vote:   this.vote.value, 
    phone:   this.phones.value

  };

  let loader = this.loading.create({

  content: 'Submitting, please wait…',

  });

  loader.present().then(() => {

  this.http.post('http://edomonitor.com/electionApi/addResult.php',data, options)

  .map(res => res.json())

  .subscribe(res => {

  loader.dismiss()

  if(res=="RESULT SUCCESSFULLY ENTERED"){

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

  //title:"CONGRATS",

  subTitle:(res),

  buttons: ['OK']

  });

  alert.present();

  this.navCtrl.push(PostPage);

  }else if(res=="YOU ARE NOT AUTHORISE TO SEND RESULT MORE THAN ONCE"){

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

      //title:"ERROR",

      subTitle:(res),

      buttons: ['OK']

      });

      alert.present();

    }else

  {

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

  //title:"ERROR",

  subTitle:(res),

  buttons: ['OK']

  });

  alert.present();

  }

  });

  });

  }

  }
```

**For clarification:**
The form has input name party[] which is defined already but in the vote input which as name vote[] is where the category votes goes to.

I am trying to find a way I could get votes for each party in the form and send it to the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Tonye would be great to learn what is the goal of this voting feature, like you dont want people to vote multiple time or not? So please provide more context

Comment: @SergeyRudenko, look at the form for instance, it has an input array name="vote[]" and also name="party[]", I am looking for a way I can send the array inputs in this format pdp 200, apc 250 e.t.c depending on the outcome of the vote

Comment: This is too “tactical” sorry, even with your comment i have no idea what is the big picture here and what you are trying to implement, going through your code on my own is too confusing:(